# Eliminating Indirect Left Recursion

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar, javacc

My brain is fried trying to eliminate some left recursion from production rules.
I'm building a compiler with JavaCC and I need to use the following 2 production rules:

```
expression := fragment ( ( + | - | * | / )  fragment )*

fragment := identifier | number | ( + | - ) fragment | expression
```

But the problem is that fragment is related to expression which is related to fragment, ie: indirect left recursion.

I've looked around the internet and everyone seems to use this algorithm which can be found [here](http://www.cs.may.ie/staff/jpower/Courses/Previous/parsing/node30.html). That site doesn't explain direct left recursion elimination which you can find [here](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~kal/PLT/PLT4.1.2.html)

I end up with rules like this:

```
void expression(): {}
{
  fragment()
  (
    (< PLUS >|< MINUS >|< DIVIDE >|< ASTERISKS >)
    fragment()
  )*
}

void k(): {}
{
  (
    ((< PLUS >|< MINUS >|< DIVIDE >|< ASTERISKS >)fragment())*k()
  | fragment()
  )
} 

void fragment(): {}
{
  (
    < ID >k()
  | number()k()
  | (< PLUS >|< MINUS >)fragment()k()
)
}
```

They're written in the code used for JavaCC so hopefully you can understand them. Basically I introduced a rule K to deal with the recursion except the problem still exists because the first part of K can be reduced to nothing because it's * (0 or more times) which leaves you with K -> k() which is more left recursion!!

I have no idea where to go from here and have lost a lot of hair. Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: You can usually have `term`, `expression` and then a terminal symbol, why isn't that good enough here?

Comment: I think that `fragment` is defined incorrectly. Shouldn't `expression` appear between literal parentheses, something like `fragment := ... '(' expression ')'`? Otherwise it makes no sense having `expression` at the `fragment` level. Note that I'm not familiar with JavaCC in particular, but that would be the problem in other parser generators.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing tenterhook. I can't seem to think of a case where that `expression` in fragment would ever be of use. However the rules are pretty much cast in stone as they were decided my a lecturer. Perhaps I should contact him?

H2CO3: Could you explain that a bit more? Do you mean I should create a rule `term`? What would it include? I actually have seen people using `term` around the net but I thought it would be better to follow that algorithm.

Comment: @carlmango11 I recommend contacting him/her about it. There is no way to resolve `expression` -> `fragment` -> `expression` without adding or removing something from the rules.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest rewriting the rule for `expression` as follows:

```
expression := ( identifier | number | ( + | - ) fragment ) ( ( + | - | * | / ) fragment )*
```

Effectively, this is just a substitution of `fragment` in the original definition, with the Kleene operator conveniently absorbing some terms.

Of course, whatever structure is created from parsing this will be need to be accommodated, if it is supposed to reflect the original rules.